# How to create my USB bootable GPT partition?

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb

This is what lsblk shows

```
sdd                    8:48   1  14,7G  0 disk 
├─sdd1                 8:49   1     2G  0 part /media/miki/Ubuntu 19.04 amd64
└─sdd2                 8:50   1   3,7M  0 part
```

This is the output of fdisk /dev/sdd

```
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdd: 14,7 GiB, 15733161984 bytes, 30728832 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x46f8e7bf

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1  *          0 4095999 4096000    2G  0 Empty
/dev/sdd2       4066772 4074259    7488  3,7M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

What should I choose now?

```
Command (m for help): m

Help:

  DOS (MBR)
   a   toggle a bootable flag
   b   edit nested BSD disklabel
   c   toggle the dos compatibility flag

  Generic
   d   delete a partition
   F   list free unpartitioned space
   l   list known partition types
   n   add a new partition
   p   print the partition table
   t   change a partition type
   v   verify the partition table
   i   print information about a partition

  Misc
   m   print this menu
   u   change display/entry units
   x   extra functionality (experts only)

  Script
   I   load disk layout from sfdisk script file
   O   dump disk layout to sfdisk script file

  Save & Exit
   w   write table to disk and exit
   q   quit without saving changes

  Create a new label
   g   create a new empty GPT partition table
   G   create a new empty SGI (IRIX) partition table
   o   create a new empty DOS partition table
   s   create a new empty Sun partition table
```

This the p output

```
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdd: 14,7 GiB, 15733161984 bytes, 30728832 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x46f8e7bf

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1  *          0 4095999 4096000    2G  0 Empty
/dev/sdd2       4066772 4074259    7488  3,7M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)


lsblk -f /dev/sdd
NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL              UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sdd    iso9660 Ubuntu 19.04 amd64 2019-04-16-19-19-59-00               
├─sdd1 iso9660 Ubuntu 19.04 amd64 2019-04-16-19-19-59-00               /media/miki/Ubuntu 19.04 amd64
└─sdd2 vfat    Ubuntu 19.04 amd64 039E-EF17
```

My goal is to make USB bootable but it was not detected because of wrong(MBR previously)type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you cloned from the iso file to the USB pendrive. Please tell us which tool/method you used.

You can check with the following command, and you should get something similar to what I get (with Lubuntu)

```
$ lsblk -f /dev/sdd
NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL               UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sdd    iso9660 Lubuntu 19.04 amd64 2019-04-16-19-13-46-00               
├─sdd1 iso9660 Lubuntu 19.04 amd64 2019-04-16-19-13-46-00               
└─sdd2 vfat    Lubuntu 19.04 amd64 039E-EF17
```

In that case the USB pendrive should be bootable both in UEFI mode and BIOS mode.

It is a very special partition table (but classified as MSDOS, not GUID (GPT). And there is no reason to try to create a GPT partition.

---

You may have to modify some setting in a UEFI/BIOS menu of your computer, or easier, hit a hotkey early during boot to get a temporary boot menu, where you can select the USB drive.

If it still does not work, you should check with `md5sum` that the download was good. The next step would be to check if the USB pendrive is good. But the output in your question looks promising.

Comment: I added lsblk output,please take a look.

Comment: @MikiBelavista, It looks like a good cloned drive, and I think you will be able to boot from it (without changing it).

Comment: @MikiBelavista, The end of life of 19.04 is in January 2020 (very soon). I suggest that you download and try Ubuntu 19.10, which will last until  July 2020, or Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with long time support until April 2023 (and with security updates for another 5 year period until April 2028).

Comment: @MikiBelavista, You are welcome and good luck :-)